# What does this image say?

Tags: выражения

[image: Мой ПК: Ну На*ер]

Can someone please explain to me what this meme is saying? I know it's not very serious, but I genuinely want to know.

Comment: Got it, I'm so sorry. First time poster here is all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top: "My PC".
Bottom: can be translated like "F*ck this" or "to hell with it". Meaning, scared of even trying, with these PC specs.

Comment: i'd not say scared, rather annoyed, snobbing, etc.
I guess without recognizing the face no more can be said about this meme idea

Comment: "The face" is obviously Father McFeely from the first 10 minutes or so of _Scary Movie 2_. [Here is that scene in Russian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcfHBgUTn7I): In the original, he said "Fuck this!"